# Effect on the shell pipe operator on stdin, stdout and stderr

Tags: shell, pipe, file-descriptors

When I create a pipe using the shell, for example:

```
ls | cat
```

What I know for sure is that the `stdin` for `cat` will be the `stdout` for `ls` (i.e. everything `ls` writes to its `stdout`, `cat` will read it through its `stdin`).

Now I have two questions:

1. Will the `stdin` for `ls` be the `stdout` for `cat`?
2. Is the `stderr` for both `ls` and `cat` affected by the pipe operator, or will it still be the inherited `stderr` value of the shell?

Comment: 1. No. 2. no, pipe does not do anything to stderr.

Answer (score 6):

Technically, in `ls | cat`

- the stdout of `ls` (its fd 1) will be the writing end of a pipe (or socketpair with ksh93 on some systems).
- the stdin of `cat` (its fd 0) will be the reading end of that same pipe
- both commands will run concurrently (are started at the same time in separate processes)
- stdin of `ls` is not affected (question 1)
- stdout of `cat` is not affected (question 1)
- stderr (fd 2) of `ls` or `cat` are not affected (question 2).

To have `ls`'s stderr also go to the writing end of the pipe (so `cat` can read it from its stdin at the other end of the pipe), you can do:

```
ls 2>&1 | cat
```

Which says: "make fd 2 point to the same resource as that on fd 1 (here the pipe)"

With `csh`, `tcsh`, `zsh` or `bash` 4.0 or above, you can also write it:

```
ls |& cat
```

On systems where pipes are bi-directional, you could do:

```
ls <&1 | cat >&0
```

to have `cat`'s stdout be fed back to `ls` via that same pipe but in the reverse direction, but that would be pointless as `ls` never reads from its stdin.

On Linux, where pipes are not bidirectional, that command would give an error.